# How to import JSON file to MS excel horizontally using VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

Hello i want to ask about some problem about excel, i have some data like this:

[image]

and i have import that JSON data to excel with modules from https://github.com/TheEricBurnett/Excellent-JSON

and my code form are

```
Private Sub ImportJSONFIle_Click()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
            .Title = "Select a JSON File"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False  
        If .Show() Then
            Filename = .SelectedItems(1)
            Dim content As String
            Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
            Open Filename For Input As #iFile
                content = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
                ' Parse JSON String
                Dim dummyData As Object
                Set dummyData = JsonConverter.ParseJson(content)
                i = 1
                For Each dummyDatas In dummyData
                    Cells(i, 1) = dummyDatas("nama")
                    Cells(i, 2) = dummyDatas("email")
                    i = i + 1
                    Next
                Close #iFile
        End If
    End With End Sub
```

finally the result is:

[image]

Here i want to ask how to make the data written horizontally not vertically? Here the result what i want :

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code in images, edit your question and paste your code in it directly.

Comment: ohh thank you for your suggestion sorry because this my first post

Comment: In future, please also post your JSON in text as well. Anything that can be text should be posted in the question as text, not image. This makes it easy for people to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you could potentially deal with alot of entries from the JSON, it is recommended to populate the values in an array first then write into your worksheet.

Replace this:

```
For Each dummyDatas In dummyData
    Cells(i, 1) = dummyDatas("nama")
    Cells(i, 2) = dummyDatas("email")
    i = i + 1
Next
```

To this:

```
Dim outputArr() As Variant
ReDim outputArr(1 To 1, 1 To dummyData.Count * 2) As Variant

For Each dummyDatas In dummyData
    outputArr(1, i) = dummyDatas("nama")
    i = i + 1
    outputArr(1, i) = dummyDatas("email")
    i = i + 1
Next

Cells(1, 1).Resize(, UBound(outputArr, 2)).Value = outputArr
```

**EDIT - To insert result after the last column**

```
Dim outputArr() As Variant
ReDim outputArr(1 To 1, 1 To dummyData.Count * 2) As Variant

For Each dummyDatas In dummyData
    outputArr(1, i) = dummyDatas("nama")
    i = i + 1
    outputArr(1, i) = dummyDatas("email")
    i = i + 1
Next

Dim lastCol As Long
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Cells(1, lastCol + 1).Resize(, UBound(outputArr, 2)).Value = outputArr
```

Comment: wowww this code is work for me thank you sir, god bless you

Comment: sorry sir, I want to ask, can we determine the result with the desired column according to excel?

Comment: @Afifabiyyuna Sorry I don't understand your question, what do you mean `determine the result with the desired column`?

Comment: @Afifabiyyuna Side-note - If an answer resolves your question, you can accept it by clicking the tick beside the answer. (If there are multiple answers to your question, you can only accept one)

Comment: the point is, for example I want the result to be from column H
because the previous result starts from column A

Comment: @Afifabiyyuna So you want the input to be after the last column?

Comment: @Afifabiyyuna Please see the edited answer, I must however warn you that there are only 16384 columns in a worksheet so you can hit the limit and get an error quite easily doing this.

Comment: no no, I'm just asking because later it will be used to add existing excel data, for example there is already excel data from columns A to D, so the results must be from column E and so on

Comment: is there any way to solve the problem sir?

Comment: @Afifabiyyuna See the edited code, it will look for the last used column and write in the data starting from the column after that.

Comment: oke, i will try it first, thank a lot sir :)

Comment: sorry sir i want to ask, how do you get the data to continue down instead of going to the left? because yesterday it was successful to continue the data to the left

Answer (score 1):

You may try to replace :

```
  Cells(i, 1) = dummyDatas("nama")
  Cells(i, 2) = dummyDatas("email")
```

with

```
  Cells(1,i) = dummyDatas("nama")
  i=i+1
  Cells(1,i) = dummyDatas("email")
```

Comment: notice that at first loop, it will be cells(1,1) and cells(1,2) but on the second loop it will overwrite cell(1,2). I think you are missing and extra line of `i=i+1` at the end

Comment: Another i=i+1 exists below the Cells(1,i) = dummyDatas("email"), so it should not overwrite cell(1,2)

Comment: Ohhh, So actually the extra `i=i+1` line exists. I understand now. Yes, it would work.

Comment: Although the solution is dirty, it should work.

Comment: yeah the result almost worked but still broken :(

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this should work. Replace this:

```
Cells(i, 1) = dummyDatas("nama")
Cells(i, 2) = dummyDatas("email")
i = i + 1
```

With:

```
Cells(1, i) = dummyDatas("nama")
Cells(1, i+1) = dummyDatas("email")
i=i+2
```

Comment: the result almost worked but still broken :(